# How to change key mapping for HOME and END keys in XTERM?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xterm

I am working on RHEL 6.4.

In my old system running on RHEL 5.3, the <kbd>Home</kbd> is mapped to `^[[1~` and <kbd>End</kbd> is mapped to `^[[4~`.

In the new system, <kbd>Home</kbd> is mapped to `^[[H` and <kbd>End</kbd> is mapped to `^[[F`, which is causing some undesirable behaviour in my application.

Please tell me how can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to [modify the keymap](http://www.jmknoble.net/old-stuff/xterm-keys.html) in xterm's [X resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources).

```
*XTerm*VT100.translations:      #override \n\
        None<Key>Home: string(0x1b) string("[1~") \n\
        None<Key>End: string(0x1b) string("[4~") \n
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can change keys using the `translations` resource, there are pros/cons.  If you do *not* use that resource, by itself `xterm` provides several other resources (including some that can be switched via menu entries).  If you use the resource, the keys cannot be switched via the menu entry.

The <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys can be switched between [*"PC-style"*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-PC-Style-Function-Keys) `^[[H` and `^[[F` to [*"VT220-style"*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-VT220-Style-Function-Keys) `^[[1~` and `^[[4~` using the **`VT220 Keyboard`** menu entry.

In addition to the menu entry, the same switching can be done using a control sequence:

```
CSI ? Pm h
          DEC Private Mode Set (DECSET).
            Ps = 1 0 6 1  -> Set VT220 keyboard emulation.
CSI ? Pm l
          DEC Private Mode Reset (DECRST).
            Ps = 1 0 6 1  -> Reset keyboard emulation to Sun/PC style.
```

which you could use in a script:

```
printf '\033[?1061h
```

changing the keyboard type to VT220.

These features predate RHEL5, by the way.  Red Hat used to override the xterm resources, as mentioned in the FAQ *[Why can't I use the home/end keys?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_pc_style)*.