# Some keys don't work in console (tty), but work in a terminal emulator

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard, console

When I am am in virtual terminal and open my editor, I can use editor key shortcuts such as <kbd>CTRL + Down</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL + Up</kbd> to select lines (select block), or  <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> to copy/move the selected block.

When I log in via console however, (tty, via <kbd>CTRL + Alt + F1</kbd>), these shortcuts no longer work. <kbd>CTRL + Down</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL + Up</kbd> act simply as <kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd> instead of copying selected block prints cappital letter `E`. Only the  <kbd>F6</kbd> works (moves selected block).

I believe this has nothing to do with my editor (`joe`), but instead has to do with settings of the console/terminal.

How can I use same keys in the tty console, as I do in virtual terminal.

Comment: Under Linux, I presume?

Comment: @Gilles - thanks, but the linked answer seems little outdated, and does not explain where you got the keycodes from.

Comment: This stuff hasn't changed since the last century, so it isn't outdated. Look at the existing keymaps to find the keycodes. If you have trouble finding the right files to look at or edit in your distribution (different distributions use different file locations and package names), you could ask a question about that.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is unrelated to *settings* of the console/terminal.  Rather, it is a feature of the terminal (or terminal emulator) itself.

The [terminfo database's](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html#download_database) [predefined *capabilities*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Predefined-Capabilities) reflect existing practice across a few thousand terminal types.  If you read through the list of predefined capabilities, you may notice that there are several definitions for *shifted* keys, e.g.,

```
   key_beg                   kbeg   @1   begin key
```

versus

```
   key_sbeg                  kBEG   &9   shifted begin key
```

There are no predefined capabilities for other modifiers such as <kbd>control</kbd>.

To make a long story short,

- the hardware terminals which served as models for modern computer console/terminal and terminal emulators *rarely* used any modifier than <kbd>shift</kbd>, and that was not used pervasively.
- computer console/terminal implementations tend to lag in development because they are part of the kernel, and innovations there interfere with stability
- Linux and BSD consoles for instance are based (loosely) on existing practice in other terminals such as VT220 for Linux and SCO for the BSDs (technically Unix for the latter, but documented as SCO).  A few changes have been made over the past twenty years, mainly with the BSDs adapting changes from xterm.
- The BSD console as adapted from SCO provided combinations of <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd> to multiply the available function keys.  `rxvt` provided a scheme like that around 1994.
- VT220s do not modify special keys using <kbd>control</kbd> (or even <kbd>shift</kbd>, for that matter).  A later DEC terminal model provides an option which was adapted in xterm in 1999, referred to as *PC-style* function keys.
- The *PC-style* modifiers implemented in xterm went beyond the <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>, adding <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>meta</kbd>.
- Other terminal developers copied the feature from xterm, and now (more than 15 years later), some users regard it as standard.
- The *extended* special keys are supported in ncurses as "user-defined" capabilities; there is no *standard* which addresses this (or actually, *any* set of function-keys).

Further reading:

- [What are the characters printed when Alt+Arrow keys are pressed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73669/what-are-the-characters-printed-when-altarrow-keys-are-pressed/274311#274311)
- [How to change key mapping for HOME and END keys in XTERM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85656/how-to-change-key-mapping-for-home-and-end-keys-in-xterm/275671#275671)
- [ncurses user-definable capabilities](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_N_C_U_R_S_E_S__U_S_E_R-_D_E_F_I_N_A_B_L_E__C_A_P_A_B_I_L_I_T_I_E_S)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The root cause is that the default key mappings on the Linux console map Ctrl+arrow keys to the same escape sequences as plain arrow keys. Your historical explanation is correct, but that *can* be changed by changing the settings of the console.